# Discard/stop tracking property value change (soapui project)

Tags: soapui

I'm using SoapUi to write tests, and git (SourceTree with Bitbucket) for version control.
After changes of properties value (after run), SourceTree prompt change of file (value change).

Is there a way to avoid these changes of properties values ?
or do you always discard it manually?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Discard the changes, as you suggested.
2. Create a small test case teardown script: `testCase.setPropertyValue(property, default)`, which will always reset the property value to some default.

Personally I give preference to #2, as that does not mess up anyone else checking stuff into source control.

Comment: It seems to be good idea, but problematic; If i want to see after a run, the test result (properties value), it will show the default, right?

Comment: Then add a `log.info(property)` first.